# c++ nested arrays[][] empty in second function

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a nested array and i am trying to pass it from one function to another

but on the other end there is no data

this is where it is initialized :

```
int myarray[4][23];
//myarray populated
int size = sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(myarray[0]);
std::cout << "AND " << size << std::endl;    //this gives me 4 as expected
function(myarray);
```

it then goes to another file and is used:

```
function(int myarray[][23]) {
    int size = sizeof(myarray) / sizeof(myarray[0]);
std::cout << "AND " << size << std::endl;    //this gives me 0
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an array to function, it is decayed to the pointer and the ability to find out its size using the `sizeof` is lost. It returns the size of pointer instead. Have a look at: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1168156)

In case of function with the following prototype:

```
void function(int myarray[][23]);
```

the type of argument is actually `int (*)[23]` so `sizeof(myarray)` returns the size of pointer, which is 4 on 32bit systems and 8 on 64bit systems.

Comment: i meant to write myarray[][23]

Comment: his answer is still valid.

Comment: @user2771826: I've edited my answer to make it more clear :)